# Always getting first record in modal when passing props to it

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using a client component in Next.js and passing props to a daisyui modal.

Basically I have a table with a list of records and each have a button next to them. When I click on the button it should open the modal with the details for that record in the modal. The console.log is showing the correct data but the modal itself always shows data for the first record.

```
"use client";
interface Props {
  booking: object;
}

const BookingEditModal = ({ booking = {} }: Props) => {
  const [selectedBooking, setSelectedBooking] = useState<any>({});

  const FetchBookingDetails = async () => {
      
    setSelectedBooking(booking);
      
    console.log(selectedBooking);  
      
    const editBookingModal = document.getElementById(
      "editBookingModal"
    ) as HTMLDialogElement;
    if (editBookingModal) {
      editBookingModal.showModal();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button className="btn btn-error" onClick={FetchBookingDetails}>
        Update
      </button>
      <dialog id="editBookingModal" className="modal">
        <div className="modal-box">
          <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">{selectedBooking.name}</h3>
          <div className="modal-action">
            <form method="dialog">
              <button className="btn">Close</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </dialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default BookingEditModal;
```

Comment: Your problem almost certainly lies in the fact that clicking your button is going to execute `FetchBookingDetails` which then is going to rerender when `setSelectedBooking` is called, but only AFTER it opens the modal for whatever `selectedBooking` was at the time of click.  The rerendered modal is never affected by `shownModal`.  If you want to fix this I wouldn't  grab elements by the DOM (this is horrible practice mixing it in with react if you have other means) and put the click action to set a new `showModal` state that the modal is responsive to..

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to not use DaisyUI and implemented another modal that uses state for showing the modal and my issue is now resolved!